How Do I Find Gnome Schema "type as" Key Options?
I am trying to find the options available for this particular Gnome Schema Key on Debian 12: org.gnome.online-accounts whitelisted-providers
At the terminal, gsettings range SCHEMA KEY works for enum type keys, but not for type as keys - which this one is.
Where or how to do find the options available for type as keys? Particularly this key?
I have tried reading the docs, but was unsuccessful...

https://developer-old.gnome.org/goa/stable/
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineAccounts/Providers
https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-online-accounts.html.en
How do I browse for available gsettings options?

Thanks.
